# String declaration initial length when not initialised

Tags: c++, c-strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     char a[20];
     cout<<strlen(a)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is `11`.
Why 11? When I have not initialised it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too basic

Answer (score 2):

As stated here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen,

> The behavior (of `strlen(str)`) is undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by str.

The issue you are facing is caused by uninitialized memory. With `char a[20];` you are only reserving memory space, but you are not initializing it. Those 20 bytes can have any possible value and you have no guarantees that any of them is set to 0. That causes the unespected return value of the `strlen()` call, you simply were lucky that the function found a byte set to 0 before it could cause a crash.

To avoid any problem you should initialize your variables before using. For a null terminated sequence of char you can initialize like so:

```
char a[20] = "";
```

Or you can use `std::string` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a;
    std::cout << a.length() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output, if you are wondering, is `0`.

Comment: This means that your result of `11` is just an arbitrary value -- it just so happens that the unitialized memory reserved for your char array had a `0` byte 11 chars in. You may get different results on other systems, including segmentation faults (i.e. crashes). In other words: be *very* careful about uninitialized memory.

Comment: @SnildDolkow you are right, thanks for adding more explanation.

Comment: It's not quite as you have stated it. There is, as it happens, a null. What is undefined is the content of `a`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You are right, of course. Thanks for editing my answer, I just rephrase a part of it to better clarify your point, but I'm afraid my English skills are even worse that my coding ones.

Answer (score 0):

- If you find uninitialized array's length,The behavior is undefined. if you want correct result initialize it. or use this:

  `int a[20] = {};`

  or

  `memset(a,'\0',20)`  and then after check the length.

Comment: Why? and if we need to initialize the array at middle of the program then or clean my junk data?

Comment: it's more prone to error. At worst use `fill( begin(a), end(a), 0 );` . Or use `std::array` with assignment operator.